# Select dropdown fails to trigger the jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When Y is selected, both of the input field should display "completed",and when user select "N", both of the input field should be blank but for some reason the code fail, any idea. Many Thanks

```js
if($('.finished1').val(''))
{
 $('.finished').val('');
 
}

else if($('.finished1').val('Y'))
{
 $('.finished').val('completed');
 
}
else{
 $('.finished').val('');
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  class="finished1">
<option value="" ></option>
<option value="Y" > Y</option>
<option value="N" > N</option>
</select>

<table>
<td><input type="text" class="finished"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="finished"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your change Function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tclynk/7eddfw3g/2/)

```
$('.finished1').on('change',function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'N' || $(this).val() == ''){
     $('.finished').val('');
   }else{
     $('.finished').val('completed');
   }
});
```

Comment: If you use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` you avoid two function calls, which is both easier to read and more efficient, and if you were to invert the if test and check for `'Y'` instead you could avoid having to check the field value twice.

Answer (score 2):

You'll first need to evaluate the value of the select box through a `change` event handler and from there you can use `switch` statement to determine what to do from there.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.finished1').on('change', function() {
    switch (this.value) {
      case 'Y':
        $('.finished').val('completed');
        break;
      case 'N':
      case: '':
        $('.finished').val('');
        break;
      default:
        //
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="finished1">
  <option value="" ></option>
  <option value="Y" > Y</option>
  <option value="N" > N</option>
</select>

<table>
  <td><input type="text" class="finished"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="finished"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: `case 'N', '':`? I don't think that does what you seem to think it does. Should be a fall-through.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: Cool. Bonus points for saying `this.value` rather than `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Hey man...whenever I have a chance to go native, I most certainly do.

Answer (score 2):

You should use jquery's Change API to capture any change in the select input then you can check the selected value and respond accordingly

```js
$('.finished1').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'Y')
    $('.finished').val('completed');
  else
    $('.finished').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  class="finished1">
<option value="" ></option>
<option value="Y" > Y</option>
<option value="N" > N</option>
</select>

<table>
<td><input type="text" class="finished"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="finished"></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a function that will detect the change in dropdown selected item.

If its detected it will check the values again and if need chang it to what is selected.

```
$(function () {
    $('.finished1').change(function () {
         if($('.finished1').val(''))
         {
         $('.finished').val('');    
         }
         else if($('.finished1').val('Y'))
         {
         $('.finished').val('completed');   
         }
         else{
         $('.finished').val('');    
         }
    });
});
```